# JS: Calling a function inside another method using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I don't know if this is possible, but how I can call the method_one.function_one() inside the method_Two.function_Two ?

```
define(function (require) {

var language = require('../language.config');

return {

    method_One: function(){

        function function_One(data){

            return true;

        }

        return {
           function_One : function_One
        }
    },

    method_Two: function(){

        function function_Two(data){

            //How to call the method_One.function_One() ?
            getValueOfFunctionOne = this.method_One().function_One();

            //Do something with result
            return getValueOfFunctionOne;
        }

        return {
           function_Two : function_Two
        }
    },
};  
});
```

Is possible to do that? Or have any other way to do?

Comment: You can't. Not with an object like this. The object can't refer to its own function. You should probably try to refactor this object, maybe turn into a class where you'll be able to access the functions.

Answer (score 0):

it should become something like this:

```
let obj = {
  meth1: () => {
    function func1() {
       return true;
    }

    return {
       func1: func1
    }
  },

  meth2: () => {
    // notice the use of "obj"
    obj.meth2().func1()
  }
}

// test it
obj.meth2(); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using local variable in the method_Two which will hold instance of the object which you are passing as a module to RequireJS:

```
 define(function (require) {

    var language = require('../language.config');

    return {

        method_One: function(){

            function function_One(data){

                return true;

            }

            return {
                function_One : function_One
            }
        },

        method_Two: function(){
            var self = this;

            function function_Two(data){

                getValueOfFunctionOne = self.method_One().function_One();

                //Do something with result
                return getValueOfFunctionOne;
            }

            return {
                function_Two : function_Two
            }
        }
    };  
});
```

Other way is to use bind to bind this to the instance of the module:

```
define(function (require) {

    var language = require('../language.config');

    return {

        method_One: function(){

            function function_One(data){

                return true;

            }

            return {
                function_One : function_One
            }
        },

        method_Two: function(){
            function function_Two(data){

                getValueOfFunctionOne = this.method_One().function_One();

                //Do something with result
                return getValueOfFunctionOne;
            }.bind(this);

            return {
                function_Two : function_Two
            }
        }
    };  
});
```

Third way is to assign the returned module to the variable and use it in the function:

```
define(function (require) {

    var language = require('../language.config');

    var module = {

        method_One: function(){

            function function_One(data){

                return true;

            }

            return {
                function_One : function_One
            }
        },

        method_Two: function(){
            function function_Two(data){

                getValueOfFunctionOne = module.method_One().function_One();

                //Do something with result
                return getValueOfFunctionOne;
            };

            return {
                function_Two : function_Two
            }
        }
    };

    return module;
});
```

Personally I think the third option is the best, it is very readable, open to extend.

Comment: Please explain in details your code blocks so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra what exactly should I explain? I added small explain, I think it is enough :)